# OSLogStore location

Tags: ios, swift, logging, oslog

I'm trying to use the new `OSLogStore` object to retrieve created logs. It's very common to see the scope initialiser used like `OSLogStore(scope: .currentProcessIdentifier)`. This works fine as long as I don't kill the app, but when I do, I cannot retrieve logs from a previous run. At least not on my simulator.

I would like to be able to persist the logs to a file and manually manage the file (if needed). So I attempted to use the `OSLogStore(url:)` initialiser, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
let url = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("logs")
try OSLogStore(url: url)

// Error Domain=OSLogErrorDomain Code=1 
// "The specified URL did not refer to a valid log archive" 
// UserInfo={
//     _OSLogErrorPOSIXErrno=2, 
//     NSLocalizedDescription=The specified URL did not refer to a valid log archive,
//     _OSLogErrorInternalCode=3
// }
```

That made me think that maybe this throws an error, as the file doesn't exist, so I also tried to write an empty file to the location and change path extensions (to `.logs`, `.log` and `.logarchive`), but so far without luck.

Is there anyone who knows how I can manually tell the `OSLog` framework at which location to store the logs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it is NOT possible to access system logs programmatically on iOS at all:

1. Logs (`.tracev3`) are stored in `/var/db/diagnostics` and your sandboxed ios app can't access them.
2. `.tracev3` is proprietary file format and `OSLog` framework doesn't have methods to work with.

`OSLogStore(url:)` allows to read `.logarchive` files only. For instance you can grab logs from your device and make this archive by running next command:

```
sudo log collect --device-name "My iPhone Name" --last 1h --output log.logarchive
```

And then `OSLogStore` can open this file and enumerate all log entries:

```swift
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "log", withExtension: "logarchive")!
let store = try OSLogStore(url: url)

try store.getEntries()
    .compactMap { $0 as? OSLogEntryLog }
    .forEach {
        print($0.date, $0.subsystem, $0.composedMessage)
    }
```

Collecting os logs with `log` command line util can be made programmatically on MacOS app but it's not possible on iOS side so that `OSLogStore(url:)` not useful on iOS either.

Comment: Is very frustrating trying to use Apple Frameworks and then not being able to collect previous logs...